# How to OrderBy an integer in a string field in a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

I have some data coming out of an DB that I can't readily change the schema of.  I want to sort it and bind it to a control based on a numerical ID.  The problem is that the API stores the number in a string field instead of as an `int` and Linq barfs on the conversion attempt.

```
myControl.DataSource = dataFromDB.OrderBy(o => int.Parse(o.StringHoldingAnInt));
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

`Convert.ToInt32` doesn't work either.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Sorting as a string isn't suitable because the values aren't all the same length and it would order them like this:  1, 10, 11, 2, 3..

Comment: How much data is there? Would it be feasible to sort on the client side?

Comment: You could try to pad the string with '0' so that they all have the same length... but I'm not sure String.PadLeft is supported by Linq.

Comment: @dlev several hundred rows in the DB, only a few dozen rows after the Where() query I omitted from my question.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Linq-to-Entities doesn't like String.PadLeft either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This won't be nearly as efficient because you're not harnessing the database query to filter your results, but this would basically query for all data, then filter on the client.

```
myControl.DataSource = dataFromDB.ToList().OrderBy(o => int.Parse(o.StringHoldingAnInt));
```

Comment: My unabridged query does a Where() prior to the order by command to cut the amount of data down to a reasonable size, so the client side processing burden shouldn't be excessive.

Comment: For those reading this: This will load the entire database table in memory.

Answer (score 16):

Came up with a simple trick to fix this: First order by length and then normaly.

```
dataFromDB.OrderBy(o => o.StringHoldingAnInt.Length).ThenBy(o => o.StringHoldingAnInt)
```

This is all done in DB and doesn't load into memory.

Comment: you'd also need to add additional logic to handle negative numbers.

Comment: @LukeTBrooks I don't believe the docs you've linked back that up.  `OrderBy` is not a conversion operator, and will not cause immediate execution.  In fact, the `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` combo is specifically designed to take advantage of deferred execution.

Comment: I actually prefer this solution because it is not dependent on any magic constants and will work for string-encoded whole numbers of any size (assuming no leading zeroes)

Comment: This seems like it should be the go-to answer in general for this problem

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to do it on the DB side. The idea is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35450462/5126411). So it does sorting by properly formatted string(zero chars are added to the left and then needed amount of chars is taken from the right)

```
myControl.DataSource = dataFromDB
    .OrderBy(o =>  DbFunctions.Right("00000" + o.StringHoldingAnInt, 7));
```

Comment: +1 for a solution using DBFunctions instead of provider specific SqlFunctions. This is a much simpler solution than replicating a variable number of zeros based on the length of the original value.

Comment: Hmmm, so what if you added a convert db func, so you could order by the result....

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the query to a list:

```
var query = ...;
var list = query.ToList();
```

Now you can order by the values by converting it:

```
list.OrderBy(o => int.Parse(o.StringHoldingAnInt));
```

The problem with this is that you are retrieving a lot of values they all come from the database and then you order in memory.

Comment: Just so no one is confused, `.OrderBy()` returns an `IEnumerable`. The `list.OrderBy()` line above will currently do nothing, since you aren't assigning the return value from `.OrderBy()` to a variable.